# PowerPoint Slider in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need make a powerpoint slider from uploaded file and display it in web browser, using ASP.Net. I want tool to make it without 3rd party library and I have tried Office Web App like this

```
<iframe id="previewer" style="width:100%;height:811px;" 
        src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?
        src=https://img.labnol.org/di/PowerPoint.ppt
 ">
</iframe>
```

But I don't want allow the client to make download for the file or cloning it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but using AngularJS.

1. First convert ppt/pptx to pdf's as they are uploaded to server (you will need Powerpoint Interop library - SaveAs method)
2. Use pdf.js on the html side to display pdf
3. You can also use a carousel control to help select each individual page on the pdf.

*Reason you need to convert to pdf - ppt/pptx is not a browser view-able format*

Comment: thanks for your response , but there are some feature in pptx like animation are disappeare in your way ...

Comment: Yes, pdf will be static pages. Animations will be lost. If you have to stick to the MS Online Doc Viewer in the iFrame then you may have to jquery to hide/remove download button from DOM.

Comment: i'm tried this method,but Cross origin policy denied me to make javascript code inside iframe because the DNS of iframe differ from my DNS